# communicating vessels formula

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I having trouble with this formula (asked first in math.Se, I didn't know the existence of physics.se)

$$
Z_1(t) = Z_e+(\sqrt{Z_1-Z_e}-\frac{2S_0}{S_1}\sqrt{2g\left(1+\frac{S_1}{S_2}\right)}.t^2
$$

where $Z_1(t)$ and $Z_2(t)$ are the levels of liquid in the vessels at time $t$, $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the cross-section areas, $S_0$ is the cross-section area of the tube that connects them, and $Z_e$ is the final height of the two vessels.

but I only get incorrect values and don't know if the formula is wrong of if its me.

For testing is use $Z_1 = 45$, $Z_2 = 5$, $S_0=2\pi{}\cdot{}0.3=1.884$, $S_1=2\pi{}\cdot{}10=62.8$ and $S_2=S_1$ and

$Z_e = \frac{S_1 Z_1 + S_2 Z_2} {S_1+S_2}=\frac {62.8{}\cdot{}45 + 62.8{}\cdot{}5}{62.8+62.8}=25$

Comment: Checking the [source of the formula](http://ressources.univ-lemans.fr/AccesLibre/UM/Pedago/physique/02/divers/vasescom.html), it seems that it's only valid until Z1(t) reaches the value Ze. Until that point the shape of the curve [looks reasonable](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+25%2B%28Sqrt%5B45-25%5D-2*1.884%2F62.8*Sqrt%5B20*%281%2B1%29%5D*t%29^2+from+0+to+12), though I haven't checked the derivation.

Comment: The sections $S$ are _areas._ One possible mistake could be that you have used the formula for the _perimeter_ of a circle, where you should be using the formula for the _area_ of a circle, cf. http://math.about.com/od/formulas/ss/areaperimeter_5.htm

Comment: @Qmechanic ,thanks a lot , this is exactly why the result was wrong

Comment: Please add an answer identifying the mistake, and accept it, so that this question gets marked as answered in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like the comment aheadd said , i was doing it wrong , using perimeter instead of area ($2\pi R$ instead of $\pi R^2$).

if you wan to watch the result look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2025%2b%28Sqrt%5B45-25%5D-%282Pi0.3%C2%B2%29/%28Pi10%C2%B2%29Sqrt%5B2%2a980%281%2b%28Pi10%C2%B2%29/%28Pi10%C2%B2%29%29%5Dt%29%C2%B2%20from%200%20to%2038)